# How to set up an Angular project for iOS universal links and Android asset links to open links in the native mobile apps

Tags: android, ios, angular, ios-universal-links, digital-assets-links

Does anyone know how I should set up my Angular project to use native mobile app linkage?

E.g.

iOS: Universal Links: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

Android: Digital Asset Links: https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/v1/getting-started

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: THere's actually quite a bit of complexity in getting deep links to work well across all apps and OSes, especially the Chrome browser.  I'd look into companies that do it for you like branch.io.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found out a few things:

1.) I've placed the *.well-known* folder in the src folder of my angular project. The *.well-known* folder contains both the *apple-app-site-association* file for iOS apps, as well as the *assetlinks.json* for android apps.

2.) In the *.angular-cli.json* configuration, I've added the *.well-known* folder to the *apps->assets* configuration.

3.) For the deployment in the *nginx.conf* file, I've added:

```
# Used to open links in the native iOS app, if available
location = /.well-known/apple-app-site-association { }

# Used to open links in the native Android app, if available
location = /.well-known/assetlinks.json { }
```